# retornar dos vistas en un controlador laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Me gustaria saber si puedo retornar dos vistas en un controlador de laravel, la versión que tengo es la 5.5 y estoy intentando de la siguiente forma:

**Controlador:**

```
            $info1 = [
                'datos'     => $datos1,
                'nombre'    => $nombre
            ];

            $info2 = [
                'datos'    => $datos2,
                'estado'   => $estado
            ];   

            $documentos1 = view('App.documentos1',['info' => $info1]);
            $documentos2 = view('App.documentos2',['info' => $info2]);

            $return = [
                'documentos1' => $documentos1,
                'documentos2' => $documentos2
            ];

            return $return;
```

**Vista 1:**

```
    <div class="col-md-12 panel-grids " style="margin-top:10px;">
   <hr>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"> <h3 class="panel-title"><b class="fa fa-money"></b> <b>Lista de Documento</b></h3> </div>
        <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Documento</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($datos as $key => $value) 
                    <tr class="warning">
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td style="width: 5px;text-align: left;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
     <hr>
</div>
```

**Vista 2:**

```
    <div class="col-md-12 panel-grids " style="margin-top:10px;">
   <hr>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"> <h3 class="panel-title"><b class="fa fa-money"></b> <b>Lista de Documento Especiales</b></h3> </div>
        <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Documento</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($datos as $key => $value) 
                    <tr class="warning">
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td style="width: 5px;text-align: left;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
     <hr>
</div>
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="stats-title">
    <h4 class="title">Documentación</h4>
    <hr>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 ">
        <div id='formulario' class="form-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="well">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    {!! $sedes !!}


                   <div id="Documentos1" class="col-md-12"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="gps" class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div id="Documentos2" class="col-md-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="stats-body"> </div>
<div class="clearfix"> </div>
```

Lo  necesito hacer así ya que las dos listas van en partes separadas del template y mediante jquery voy a ubicar los valores retornados pero cuando retorno la variable `$return;` esta regresa vacía pero si retorno la variable `$documentos1` o `$documentos2` , si retorna la vista.

Answer (score 1):

¿Porqué no compones la vista utilizando blade?

Con `@include('plantilla')` puedes incluir otras "vistas" (plantillas).

Pongamos un ejemplo:

template.blade.php

```
@include('plantilla1')
@include('plantilla2')

<!-- resto de html -->
```

Controller.php

```
$info1 = [
    'datos'     => $datos1,
    'nombre'    => $nombre
 ];

$info2 = [
    'datos'    => $datos2,
    'estado'   => $estado
];   

return view('template')
                        ->with('info1', $info1)
                        ->with('info2', $info2);
```

De esta forma tendrás disponible ambas variables en la plantillas implicadas.

Puedes revisar la documentación para más información: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade

Comment: Gracias por responder @Xerif , lo que pasa es que si bien es cierto que podría hacer lo que me comentas, para el nivel en el que estoy enviando el retorno no me funcionaria ya que dentro de template estoy haciendo varias cosas y solo necesito recargar dos div con información separada que que se muestra en base a la petición ajax que realizo, una solución que implemente momentaniamente fue con jquery de extraer la información del div y re ubicarla pero es una solución que no me agrada mucho

Comment: Yo tengo algo que pudiera parecerse: Cargo una vista y esta, a su vez, carga otra. El ajax devuelve la segunda vista y la pone en el elemento que le corresponde.